# how do i solve this error am trying to add my flutter app to web

Tags: flutter, web

Because every version of google_map_location_picker depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, every version of google_map_location_picker requires intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2.
So, because medivic depends on both intl ^0.16.1 and google_map_location_picker ^3.3.3, version solving failed.

Answer (score 0):

try to change `minSdkVersion` to higher version and `compileSdkVersion` to 30 in your build.gradle file (android/app/build.gradle).

```
  compileSdkVersion 30
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

run flutter clean

if it doesn't work then go to external libraries/flutter plugins/perticular plugin which showing error/android/build.gradle/

In build.gradle file change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

and compare this file with your build.gradle and change

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

run flutter clean

Answer (score 0):

This is because `google_map_location_picker` has restriction `intl: '>=0.16.0 <=0.16.1'`

Workaround: Add this to `pubspec.yaml` :

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

Make sure to test the plugin again in case this caused any issues